# MVVM NotifyPropertyChanged

Tags: c#, mvvm

I want to ask you, how can I reflect changes on View, when I changed source. Here's my code. **MODEL:**

```
public class ExecutionMode
{
    private List<DayItem> _dayItems = new List<DayItem>();

    public enum TypeMode
    {
        None,
        Once,
        Daily,
        Weekly
    }

    public TypeMode Mode { get; set; }
    public DateTime? ExecutionTime { get; set; }
    public DateTime? ExecutionDate { get; set; }
    public List<DayItem> DayItems { get { return _dayItems; } set { _dayItems = value; } }
}
public class ProfileRecord
    {
        private ExecutionMode _mode = new ExecutionMode();
        public ExecutionMode ExecutionMode { get { return _mode; } set { _mode = value; } }
    }
```

**ViewModel**

```
    public class NewProfileViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {private ProfileRecord _record = new ProfileRecord();
public ProfileRecord Record { get{return _record; } set{_record=value; OnPropertyChanged("Record")}}
```

XAML:

```
<toolkit:TimePicker Header="Time of execution:" Margin="12,0,70,0" Value="{Binding ProfileRecord.ExecutionMode.ExecutionTime, Mode=TwoWay}" Visibility="{Binding ElementName=lpickerExecutionModes, Path=SelectedItem, Converter={StaticResource VisibilityConvert}, ConverterParameter=Once|Daily|Weekly}" />
```

When I set somewhere in code Record.ExecutionTime = Time it doesn't reflect on View. So I'm asking. Should I implement NotifyPropertyChanged in Model too?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 ways of solving the problem:

1. Implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` on your Model class
2. Map all necessary properties from Model object as a properties within `ViewModel` and implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` on those properties.

I prefer the first approach, especially when model is really huge, has a lot of properties, and all these properties are used in View.

Comment: So I should implement INotifyPropertyChanged in class ProfileRecord, and use it for public ExecutionMode ExecutionMode { get { return _mode; } set { _mode = value; } }? Right?

Comment: You have to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` on every property that is bindable from `View`, no matter what class it really belongs to.

Comment: @JurajP: Yes, but the actual implementation of the ExMode{get;set} you just pasted should actually contain the raise-INPC-notification in its setter :)

Comment: @quetzalcoatl: Yes I know. What if I have a model with main type ex. ProfileRecord, and this contains a lot of public properties with my custom types. Is it correct to implement INPC for every property?